# Algebraically solving a system of equations in two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would appreciate an algebraic explanation to the system
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}
(
(7t + 21x)(-7t+21x)(7t+7x)(7t-7x) = (2^{2} \cdot 49)^{2} \\
(8t+24x)(-8t+24x)(8t+8x)(8t-8x) = (2^{2} \cdot 64)^{2} \\
(9t+9x)(-3t+9x)(3t+9x)(9t-9x) = (2^{2} \cdot 27)^{2}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
of equations in the variables $t$ and $x$ having solutions $x = \pm \sqrt{5/3}$ 
and $t = \pm\sqrt{3}$.

The system of equations is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
(t + 3x)(-t+3x)(t+x)(t-x) = 2^{4}
\end{equation*}
and to
\begin{equation*}
(t^{2} - x^{2})(t^{2} - (3x)^{2}) = -2^{4} .
\end{equation*}
Why are the only solutions to this equation $x = \pm \sqrt{5/3}$ 
and $t = \pm\sqrt{3}$  ?

Comment: How about cancelling all those factors of $7$, $8$ and $9$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations are all the same, namely
$$
(t^2-9x^2)(t^2-x^2)+16=0
$$
that becomes
$$
t^4-10x^2t^2+9x^4+16=0
$$
This is a biquadratic in $t$:
$$
t^2=5x^2\pm4\sqrt{x^4-1}
$$
and requires $|x|\ge1$. For any $x$ with $|x|>1$ we get four distinct solutions for $t$. Just two for $|x|=1$, namely $t=\pm\sqrt{5}$.

If we consider the equation as a biquadratic in $x$, the discriminant is nonnegative for $t^4\ge9$, that is, $|t|\ge\sqrt{3}$ and we have
$$
x^2=\frac{5t^2\pm4\sqrt{t^4-9}}{9}
$$
For $t=\pm\sqrt{3}$ we have
$$
x^2=\frac{15}{9}=\frac{5}{3}
$$
that is, $x=\pm\sqrt{5/3}$, but this is certainly not the unique set of solutions.

For instance, with $x=\pm\sqrt{5/3}$, we get
$$
t^2=\frac{25}{3}\pm4\sqrt{\frac{25}{9}-1}=
\frac{25}{3}\pm\frac{16}{3}
$$
so we get $t^2=3$ *or* $t^2=41/3$.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Would you like to guess why Wolfram offers only $x = \pm\sqrt{5/3}$ and $t = \pm\sqrt{3}$ as solutions to $(t^{2} - x^{2})(t^{2} - (3x)^{2}) = -2^{4}$?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire No, I wouldn't. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}
(
(7t + 21x)(-7t+21x)(7t+7x)(7t-7x) = (2^{2} \cdot 49)^{2} \\
(8t+24x)(-8t+24x)(8t+8x)(8t-8x) = (2^{2} \cdot 64)^{2} \\
(9t+9x)(-3t+9x)(3t+9x)(9t-9x) = (2^{2} \cdot 27)^{2}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}$$ Cancel  power of 7,8,3 to$$\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}
(
(t + 3x)(-t+3x)(t+x)(t-x) = 16 \\
(t+3x)(-t+3x)(t+x)(t-x) =16\\
(t+x)(-t+3x)(t+3x)(t-x) =16
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}$$ We get all identical equations.

It remains to solve $$(t+x)(-t+3x)(t+3x)(t-x) = 16$$

The given solutions satisfy this equation but I am not sure if that is the only set of solutions that we can get out of it.